# Walker_Nav_Menu: Items not nested correctly

Tags: menus

I want to add "anchor" tag adjacent to every "list item" that has children.

this is my Walker_Nav_Menu class:

```
class Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

    $ident = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );

    if ( $args->walker->has_children ) {

        $classes = 'menu-item-has-children menu-item menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        // actual link
        $output .= "$ident<li class=\"$classes\"><a href=\"$item->url\">$item->title</a></li>\n";

        // added tag after
        $output .= "<a class=\"added\" href=\"#\">txt</a>";

    } else {

        $classes = 'menu-item menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        // actual link
        $output .= "$ident<li class=\"$classes\"><a href=\"$item->url\">$item->title</a></li>\n";
    }
}
```

This is the structure of the menu in WordPress:

[image]

But the output is not nested correctly as you can see in image below:

[image]

Please help me fix this problem

Comment: Of course they’re not nested correctly. You close li tag in your start_el, so how could they be correct ;)

Comment: @Krzysiek Dróżdż omg you're correct, I was trying to solve this problem for the last 2 hours, removing the li closing tag solved it thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this problem, because of your code ;)

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

    $ident = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );

    if ( $args->walker->has_children ) {

        $classes = 'menu-item-has-children menu-item menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        // actual link
        // you SHOULDN'T close the li tag in here
        $output .= "$ident<li class=\"$classes\"><a href=\"$item->url\">$item->title</a></li>\n";

        // added tag after
        $output .= "<a class=\"added\" href=\"#\">txt</a>";

    } else {

        $classes = 'menu-item menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        // actual link
        // you SHOULDN'T close the li tag in here
        $output .= "$ident<li class=\"$classes\"><a href=\"$item->url\">$item->title</a></li>\n";
    }
}
```

In your `start_el` you close the `li` tag, so children can't be printed inside of it...